# How do you write linq-to-xml for data between XML elements?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse some XML that looks similar to this:

```
<document>
    <headings>
        Important heading stuff.
    </headings>
    <startGroup group="1" />
        <startItem value="1" />Item one stuff<endItem />
        <blockofdata>
            <startItem value="2" />Item two stuff<endItem />
            <startItem value="3" />Item three stuff<endItem />
        </blockofdata>
        <startItem value="4" />Item four stuff<endItem />
    <endGroup />
    <startGroup group="2" />
        <startItem value="1" />Item one stuff<endItem />
        <startItem value="2" />Item two stuff<endItem />
        <startItem value="3" />Item three stuff<endItem />
    <endGroup />
</document>
```

I cannot figure out a linq-to-xml statement to get what I want.  I need to flatten the structure.  So assuming the above XML, I would like to get a list of this POCO:

```
class Items
{
    public int GroupNumber {get;set;} // group property of startGroup
    public int ItemNumber {get;set;} // value property of startItem
    public string ItemText {get;set;}  // data between i
}
```

How do you write a linq-to-xml statement that would pull the data between the attributes into the above item while grabing the data from between startGroup/endGroup and the data between startItem/endItem?  I have burned up several hours on this and am about to just switch to using a XML stream reader and parsing it the old fashioned way.

Comment: @Jeff, the C# xml reader is not throwing any errors.  I can get the attributes from the elements with my linq statment.  What makes it invalid?  Perhaps that is why I cannot get it to work.  (I fixed my typo in it).

Comment: Ok looking at it again, I guess it's not really invalid, just very unorthodox.  I tried reading that in and I was just getting a whole bunch of errors.  I don't know what happened there but it's reading fine now.

Comment: Yes, unorthodox to be sure.  It may be that linq-to-xml cannot work with how that data was formatted, but I thought I try to see if anyone as done this before with xml like this.

Comment: I'm writing up an answer right now.  It'll be a awkward but doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to use the `ElementsAfterSelf()` and `NodesAfterSelf()` methods to grab the sibling nodes along with the `TakeWhile()` predicate to stop enumerating at the appropriate times.

First the helper methods:

```
public static Items ItemsFromStartItem(XElement start, XElement group)
{
    return new Items
    {
        GroupNumber = (int)group.Attribute("group"),
        ItemNumber = (int)start.Attribute("value"),
        ItemText = start.NodesAfterSelf()
            .TakeWhile(n => n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element
                         || ((XElement)n).Name != "endItem")
            .OfType<XText>()
            .Select(t => t.Value)
            .Single()
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<Items> ItemsFromBlockOfData(
    XElement block, XElement group)
{
    return block.Elements("startItem")
        .Select(start => ItemsFromStartItem(start, group));
}
```

And the magic query.

```
var query = doc.Descendants("startGroup")
    .SelectMany(group => group.ElementsAfterSelf()
        .TakeWhile(e => e.Name != "endGroup")
        .SelectMany(e => e.Name == "startItem"
            ? new[] { ItemsFromStartItem(e, group) }
            : ItemsFromBlockOfData(e, group))
    );
```

Now I hope you did not design this XML yourself... this is the kind of stuff that can really push someone over the edge.  ;)

Comment: No, I did not design that XML, but I am doing ETL work on it.  I'll try this out tonight and post back here.  Thanks much.